# As much as possible to the left/right?

Tags: prepositions, phrases

How can I tell someone to stay to the right? Or go to the right?

Should it be:

> Stay(go) as much as possible to the right/left.
>
> Stay(go) as far as possible to the right/left.

If none of the examples above are correct, could you please give me correct example or phrases that I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#2. "Stay as far as possible to the right" or "Stay as far to the right as possible."

If talking about a turn, we often say "Make a hard right" or "Make a sharp right", as opposed to "veer right", which means just slightly to the right.